# connect not working in recursive components

Tags: reactjs, recursion, redux, redux-saga

I have certain scenario in my application where i have used **component recursion**. When i call the component recursively then state on recursive component gets undefined because somehow connect is not working on recursive component.

component which calls itself does have state but recursive component won't have state

I have tried one solution, which is that when component call it's self then it will pass all the state to it as props rather than it takes from connect

But I want to know why connect does not works on recursive component

I have to tried to recreate a scenario on codesandbox, here is [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-saga-example-forked-s9n2g?file=/src/child.js)

Thank You

Comment: When that link to a 3rd party site stops working, this question will become difficult to understand. Links to 3rd party sites can supplement your question, but if the link stops working, your question should still be answerable. I don't believe this question would pass that test. Please include the relevant code in your answer, as text.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-using the Base component, not the `connected` one.

Insted of

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Child);
```

you could use

```
const ConnectedChild = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Child);
export default ConnectedChild;
```

and use the `ConnectedChild` inside the `Child` for the recursion.

Updated demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-saga-example-forked-cz71t?file=/src/child.js